# SSH - terminal misbehaving when SSH invoked from a `while read` loop

Tags: bash, ssh, terminal, console

I'm coding a Bash script to automate tasks across multiple servers.

I am logging to a Centos 7 machine over SSH to run some editor (`nano`, `vi`, ...)

```
ssh -tt centos@... '/bb/Conf edit'
```

The `/bb/Conf edit` is basically just `vi /bb/conf.yaml`.

When I run the SSH command from my shell, it works fine. However, when the same SSH command is ran from a Bash script inside a `while read ...; do` loop, the editor has wrong size (80x40 I guess) and seems to ignore the keys I press - i.e. in `nano`, Ctrl+x doesn't do anything. The only key that works is Ctrl+c which closes the connection.

I thought this is something related to the `TERM` variable, as per [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/199052/can-i-change-terminal-type-used-to-login-through-ssh), so I tried to add `export TERM=xterm` or `TERM=rxvt` to `/bb/Conf` or the place calling the SSH. The variable is in fact set in the target environment (I've tried `echo $TERM` right before `vi`). But the terminal still misbehaved.

Then I have tried to put just that single command `ssh ...` to a new script. When running that, the editor worked fine.

After a while I found out that it works outside a `while read` loop, but not inside. I assume that the editors do some stdin/stdout magic and then `read` somehow breaks that.

Is there a way to run an editor like `vi` or `nano` from within a loop?

(The purpose in my case is to allow the users to edit files on multiple servers.)

Comment: It turns out that somehow it it broken by `while read HOST_; do` which the `ssh` is inside. I will rewrite the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because both `read` and `ssh` are reading from the same input stream. The solution is to use a different file descriptor for the while read loop:

```
while IFS= read -r -u3 line; do
    ssh ...
done 3< file
```

Here, we're using file descriptor 3 instead of stdin.

---

Lengthy pipelines can be hard to read and maintain, but you can use whitespace constructively: newlines are allowed following `|` and `&&` and `||`. Also, parentheses introduce a subshell which contains an arbitrary script, so indentation helps.

```
while read -u3 line; do
    : do stuff here that needs to read from stdin
done 3< <(
    command 1 of the pipeline |
    command 2 |
    command 3
)
```

That's clean and readable. The downside is that it puts the last part of the pipeline (the while loop) first, so the code kind of flows backwards.

Comment: If the loop is reading output from a command (or pipeline), you can use `done 3< <(somecmdorpipeline)` instead of a regular pipeline. Note that this is a bash-only feature, so use a bash shebang in the script, and don't override it by running it with the `sh` command.

Comment: Yes, it's from a pipeline which is a bit lengthy. I assume there's no way to have this with the `|` left-to-right syntax?

Comment: Also maybe I could use some other loop? The lines it consumes are just hostnames.

Comment: What is the `IFS=` for? I mean, I know it sets the separator but what does it do here?

Comment: That's the recipe for reading a line from a file **exactly**. If you don't use `IFS=` then any leading/trailing whitespace will be ignored. `IFS= read -r line` sets the IFS variable to the empty string only for the duration of the read command. The `-r` option instructs read to handle backslashes as just normal characters instead of the start of an escape sequence.